# plotting two different types of histogram plots in gnuplot on top of each other

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

I am working with a histogram in gnuplot and I want to put one of the histogram bars behind the other results. I would like the reference bar (Mörk spennubjögunar > 200 kV) to behind the other histogram bars. I have done this in excel before using different y-axis, is there a nice way to do this in gnuplot?

[image: Histogram plot I am working with]

This is the code I am currently working with.

```
set terminal pngcairo transparent nocrop enhanced size 3200,2400 font "arial,40" 
set output "Harmonic_currents_BRE.png"
set key right

set datafile separator ";"

set style line 12 lc rgb '#808080' lt 0 lw 1
set style line 13 lt 0 lw 3
set grid back ls 12

set xrange [-1:20]
set yrange [0:8]
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid border 0
set border lw 2
set boxwidth 0.7

set ylabel "Hlutfall af nafnspennu [%]"
set xlabel "Tíðni [pu 50 Hz base]"


plot "case0.csv"  using 2:xticlabels(1) title 'Tilfelli 0',\
     "case1.csv"  using 2:xticlabels(1) title 'Tilfelli 1',\
     "case2.csv"  using 2:xticlabels(1) title 'Tilfelli 2',\
     "case3.csv"  using 2:xticlabels(1) title 'Tilfelli 3',\
     "ref.csv"    using 2:xticlabels(1) title 'Mörk spennubjögunar > 200 kV'

unset output
unset zeroaxis
unset terminal
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, the best way is to first plot the reference `with boxes` with a fixed boxwidth (I used `0.9`), and then the clustered histograms:

```
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid noborder
set boxwidth 0.7

plot "ref.csv" using 0:2:(0.9):xtic(1) with boxes title 'Mörk spennubjögunar > 200 kV',\
     for [i=0:3] sprintf("case%d.csv", i) u 2 title sprintf('Tilfelli %d), i)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply I am using gnuplot 5 and it changes to errorbars when I try to use this method: "This plot style does not work with 3 cols. Setting to yerrorbars"

Comment: Uargh, yes, I missed the central part `with boxes` for the ref plot